# how to disable right click on desktop in gnome flashback but not in applications?

Tags: gnome-flashback

Trying to figure out how to disable the right click on the desktop of a kiosk user but not on applications.  Is there a code or setting that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

No. Desktop / icons are provided by nautilus and from what I know there is no such setting. I guess your only option is to disable desktop window, but then you will lose icons on it.